# Line of code clarification

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, stack

I'm reading a book about bufferoverflows and shellcode, and in the book there is this code below.

I understand most of it except the purpose of `buffer = command +strlen(command);`.

When I use `memset()` on the buffer doesn't it overwrite what I stored there previously with `command+strlen(command)`?
Can someone clarify it for me?

[image: code]

Comment: Increment the pointer.

Comment: `command` is pointing to a null-terminated string of characters, and `buffer` is set to point to the end of that null-terminated string of characters.

Comment: Don't post images of code but post the code.. -1

Comment: No. `buffer = command+strlen(command)` set the pointer to that specific address. `memset` write values to the memory pointed by `buffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one of the operands of `+` is a pointer then C does pointer arithmetic.

The result or `pointer + number` is a pointer value that points to the value with index `number`. It is equivalent to `&pointer[number]`.

So, in this case:

```
buffer = command + strlen(command);
```

is equivalent to

```
buffer = &command[strlen(command)];
```

So `buffer` will point to the string terminator in `command`, which is just the right place if you want to concatenate something to the `command` string.

Comment: Oh, so when I use memset it will store it in the memory right after the string terminator. thanks. i just dont know why im gettin so many thumbs down for asking this question

Comment: @pedrosantos Not right after. **On** the string terminator. (Regarding downvotes: don't post code as an image. Post code as text or you will get some downvotes.)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will post the code from now on